# Effect for smooth scrolling over slider/carousel

Tags: scrolling, sliders, carousel, html5

What is this effect called?

http://ruudvaneijk.nl/

when you scroll down you see it scrolls a bit over the slider on the top.
I searched the internet for half an hour but could not find how it's called.
I think it's a html5 feature.

Hope someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect is called parallax scrolling. And I am not sure if this type of question belongs to UX related community.

Comment: yes that's true i think it belongs to another SE site. but thanks :)